# Can Google Cloud Endpoints be used to create an API for a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, google-cloud-endpoints

Is Google Cloud Endpoints only intended for App Engine use, or can it be used from anywhere, including our rails app running on Amazon EC2?

Answer (score 1):

You can send requests to an endpoint from any client or server you like. At the end of the day, it's just HTTP. The endpoint code has to run on Google's servers, but anyone can call it. One of the major use cases is to provide backends for mobile apps.